# Select Text in Input On Focus Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 fields for API keys (test and live, secret and public) all with the class of `.key`

I'm trying to get a select of the input value on focus of the input.

The input looks like so:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="live_public_key" 
    class="form-control text-center key" 
    value="API key here" 
    readonly>
```

I've searched all over and the common answer to this seems to be something similar to this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('focus', '.key', function() {
        this.select();
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work.

It selects the text for a milli-second the deselects it and seems to move the focus back to the input itself.

I don't know if this is a bootstrap thing or if I've coded something wrong.

Comment: Why do you want the value on focus? onchange might suit you better because that is the value that is actually selected. i.e $('select').change(function(){return $('option:selected',this).val();});

Comment: This isn't a select list, it's an input field, a text field.

Comment: Ah sorry, onchange works for inputs aswell. You can also use on click as an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is geting *unselected* on `mouseup`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.key', function() {
    this.select();
}).on('mouseup', '.key', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7m7z47x/)

Comment: I like this answer better as it works out __why__, rather than finding a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use a workaround:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('focus', '.key', function() {
        var that = this;
        window.setTimeout (function(){ 
            that.select(); 
        }, 100);
    });
</script>
```